# Appcelerator Android Custom Fonts not working

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, custom-font

I am using custom fonts for android app. But it looks like its not working in classicJs app with `SDK 5.2.2`

I have tried making a new test project to test fonts but its also not working in test project. I am using `GothamBook` and `GothamBold` mainly. But its look like its not working for other fonts as well. for example `SpicyRice-Regular`

I am using `Appcelerator Studio`, `build: 4.5.0.201602170821` with latest `SDK 5.2.2.GA`. you can check test app [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ess7fqxt4b3w4y2/FontTest.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently it was a trivial mistake. The folder name which have all the fonts files should be named 'fonts' not 'font'.

The other thing that I noticed, if you are using non alloy (classicJs) approach the folder name which contain your all app code and assets should be named 'Resources' not 'resources' .. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Custom fonts are a quick and easy way to personalize or brand your
>   application. Titanium Mobile supports TrueType and OpenType fonts on
>   both iOS and Android. There are some differences between how fonts are
>   referenced on iOS and Android that need to be considered.
>
> Android expects fontFamily to be the font's file name without the file
>   extension (.otf or .tff). iOS expects fontFamily to be the font's
>   PostScript name (see Finding a font's PostScript name). This name is
>   embedded in the font file and does not change if you rename the file.
>
> For example, in the following code the file name of the Burnstown Dam
>   font is "burnstown_dam.otf". For an Android application you therefore
>   assign the value burnstown_dam to fontFamily:

```
"#burnstowndam": { 
  font: {
      fontFamily: 'burnstown_dam'
  }
}
```

The PostScript name for Burnstown Dam is BurnstownDam-Regular, so for an iOS application you assign that value to fontFamily:

```
"#burnstowndam": { 
  font: {
      fontFamily: 'BurnstownDam-Regular'
  }
}
```

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Custom_Fonts